# Having issues with screen capture code

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm using this bit of code to capture the iPad screen. I keep getting an error message with "self.view.layer"

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window.bounds.size, window.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly Add  QuartzCore framework in Your Project  and add

#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >

at the top of you viewController.m file

Comment: Thanks I just figured that out. Got it to run but it's not working on the iPad. Pic is not showing up in photo album. Is there a way to have the pic sent as an email attachment?